# Thread process in linux

Tags: linux, scheduling, thread

I'm wondering about the "punishment" that occurs when a new thread is created.

From my understanding of clone(2), NPTL (New POSIX Thread Library), CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler), when a new thread is created it is seen as a new process because NPTL uses a 1:1 thread model.

From what I've [read](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/completely-fair-scheduler) about the scheduler, when a new process is added to the run-queue, the `fair_clock` variable increases to a fraction of the wall clock.

From poking around the rituals with pthread_create(3), clone is eventually called just like it would in a fork(2).

Now, a process will have a 1:1 model and so will threads. So, does a thread also suffer this **same exact fate** as well?  Obviously, a thread must be punished in some form or else a muti-threaded process can hog most of the CPU time by filling up the RR (round robin) system that CFS uses.

If this ***is*** true, then what are the advantages of using threads over forks? Is it just the automatic shared heap space (as opposed to using shm_open(2))?

Comment: The doc you link to doesn't describe CFS (the book is from ~ 2000, CFS was introduced in ~2007), that "halving the timeslice" doesn't happen directly with CFS - it doesn't have traditional timeslices.

Comment: Oh, and "just the shared <strike>heap space</strike> address space" is not a detail at all, it is a completely different model from separate processes and requires very different programming techniques.

Comment: @Mat You're right, even the 3rd edition which covers 2.6 was copyrighted in 2006 and from core.c mentions 2007-04-15. Here's to hoping a 4th comes out soon. I'll read some of the code and try to edit the post.

Comment: @Mat edited for CFS now and linking to a LJ article.

Comment: Correct, the reason to use a thread rather than a separate process is when you want shared address space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link I provided about the Completely Fair Scheduler, we see that in kernel 2.6.24 has what is called group scheduling.

To quote from Chandandeep Singh Pabla:

> For example, let's say there is a total of 25 runnable processes in the system. CFS tries to be fair by allocating 4% of the CPU to all of them. However, let's say that out of these 25 processes, 20 belong to user A while 5 belong to user B. User B is at an inherent disadvantage as A is getting more CPU power than B. Group scheduling tries to eliminate this problem. It first tries to be fair to a group and then to individual tasks withing that group. So, CFS with group scheduling enabled, will allocate 50% of the CPU to each user A and B. The allocated 50% share of A will be divided among A's 20 tasks, while the other 50% of the CPU time will be distributed fairly among B's 5 taks.

Now, this applies to the above question, because when a process spawns a new thread, it'll be in that processes scheduling group. This prevents a program that spawns 1000 threads from hogging all of the CPU time, because it'll only get 1/1001th (1000 threads plus the original program) of that particular process group's run time.

So, by slowing down how much time a thread gets compared to the whole system, this properly punishes threaded applications.

Comment: 1) I can't find the link here; it should be put in the answer anyway; 2) the quote only talks about _users_ getting their own sched groups.  But the conclusion written here glosses over that; it implies this will work the same when a system has only one active user running multiple processes.